# How do I use 'this-as' in ClojureScript?

Tags: jquery, clojurescript

How do I use **this-as** in ClojureScript?

An example would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to get **this** in way of:

```
$(selection).click(function(){
   alert(this);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it. Here's an example:

```
(bind ($ "selection") "click"
    (this-as somename
        (js/alert somename)))
```